# Too many connections on remotemysql.com

Tags: mysql, remote-access, remote-mysql

I have been using a database hosted on remotemysql.com for few months and used it with a node.js discord bot.I've tried to connect to the database recently with php but forgot to close the connection. No I can't connect anywhere to the remotemysql.com database.
Not in mysql Workbench, node.js, php...

I get this error:

```
(08004/1040): Too many connections in ...
```

If I try to go to the webpage remotemysql.com I can't login because the page doesn't load.

Can I change max connections? Or close all connections?

Thanks in advance

Comment: remotemysql.com is down now. the is not a perfect cloud solutions to store data you can try https://www.jawsdb.com/docs/ bur remember it;s just free for small amount of data

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's an issue that's needs to be discussed with/solved by the third party's support.

Comment: Are there any other free hosting services to use for a remote mysql database? I've tried some others but can't seem to have them work.
I'll have a look at jawsdb.com/docs

Comment: http://db4free.net has proven to be a long-term free remote MySQL server but it's often slow enough and I've been recently getting the "Too many connections" error messages there anyways, too